# All these books may be had of any bookseller.('be had')

Tags: phrase-usage, formal-language

> All these books may be had of any bookseller.

I came across the above sentence, which I discovered was taken from the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00103269;jsessionid=A29EA4950EFEAB14AA8E25809EC5B5F4), and thought that 'be had' would rarely or never be used.

Does the sentence look idiomatic?

Comment: If you can't provide the actual source, (ie the book that the dictionary is quoting) there isn't enough context.  It looks old fashioned.  but there may be a reason for that.

Comment: You see a sentence, you say it's from a dictionary, why not tell us *which* dictionary you got it from? Why would you expect users to have to google? I don't know...

Comment: The OED's examples all seem to come from old advertisements. It looks like a traditional form of words which lasted a long time, but is now obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 'had of' in that way to mean 'bought or obtained from' is very old-fashioned, but not wrong.